# The qqnorm and qqline residuals plot yield a straight line output

Tags: regression, residuals, outliers, qq-plot

can it be considered as normality of residuals or is there any error pertaining to the regression model designed?
the dependent variable is numerical while the predictor is characters
[image]

Comment: You have some whopping big outliers.  They are so large, in fact, that you can't tell anything else about the residuals from this plot.  To go further, redo the plot after removing the most extreme values.

Comment: Something else to consider is if you want to consider your results to be normally distributed if you get a normal-looking plot with those extreme “outliers” removed.